# MOS gain, how much is it, Bipolar as a key

Tags: npn

Sorry for the stupid question. Is the MOSFET with current gain or voltage gain? I know it's voltage controlled, but what's the gain from Gate to Drain? And how do I calculate it? I know in key mode the voltage from the source is transmitted to the load.

Another question. I'm trying to load an accumulator through a transistor. If I use Bipolar, which is current controlled, how do I calculate the current and the voltage over the accumulator in key mode? I'm guessing the current will be equal to the voltage on the source-Ucesat divided by the emitter resistor or emitter and collector resistor?

**edit:**

I was left with the impression a bipolar controls a MOS for IGBT, my mistake.But thats not the topic.
My question is, for MOS → gate voltage amplified or gate current? So in the source we have the amplified voltage or current? It's not in key mode for PWM!

**edit:**

I didn't got the transfer characteristics, since it should be base current × coefficient = collector current. But bipolar is certainly current controlled. IGBT is a bipolar controlling a mos.
I know that the bipolar has electricity amplification coefficient. Base current × coefficient = collector current.
What does the MOS have?

Comment: What is "key mode"?

Answer (score 1):

Both devices (MOSFET and bipolar transistor) are voltage-controlled.
They have no "gain" and their transfer characteristics are described by the transconductance **gm=dI(out)/dV(in)**. This transconductance is nothing else than the slope of the transfer curve I(out)=f(Vin).

BJT: I(out)=Ic; V(in)=Vbe

FET: I(out)=Id; V(in)=Vgs